# Hitech compiler Compile issue

Tags: compiler-errors, microcontroller, pic, microchip

I am using PIC16F886 with hitech compiler 9.60. Here is below code I am trying to compile.
If I am using compiler v9.86 that is free version below code compile properly and do proper working.
If I am using Pro version of compiler v 9.60 I used to get an error. The error is attached below. How to get rid of this issue. How variable should be declared.

```
#include <pic.h>
#include <htc.h>
#include "delay.h"

__CONFIG(INTIO & WDTEN & PWRTEN & MCLREN & UNPROTECT & BOREN & IESODIS & FCMDIS & LVPDIS & DEBUGDIS);
__CONFIG (BORV40 & WP2);
//__EEPROM_DATA(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);




 typedef union 
     {
         struct
         {
            unsigned S0 :1;
            unsigned S1 :1;
            unsigned S2 :1;
            unsigned S3 :1;
            unsigned S4 :1;
            unsigned S5 :1;
            unsigned S6 :1;
            unsigned S7 :1;
         };
         unsigned char S0_7; 
     }USensor;

     USensor sen;
     unsigned char a;

     void main (void)
     {
         for(;;)
         {
             sen.S0 = 1;
             sen.S1 = 0;
             sen.S2 = 1;
             sen.S3 = 0;
             sen.S4 = 1;
             sen.S5 = 0;
             sen.S6 = 1;
             sen.S7 = 0;

             a = sen.S0_7;
         }
     }
```

Error message

> Error   [285] C:\Users\Testing\Test.c; 25.2 no identifier in declaration Error   [255] C:\Users\Testing\Test.c; 36.8 not a member of the struct/union ""
>       Error   [255] C:\Users\Testing\Test.c; 37.8 not a member of the struct/union ""
>       Error   [255] C:\Users\Testing\Test.c; 38.8 not a member of the struct/union ""

Comment: I think the 9.6 didn't accept anonymous structure. Try to give a name.

Comment: And be sure you have adjustet the include directory in your compiler settings correct.